# How to batch rename files and convert datestamp from DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, rename, timestamps

I am trying to rename a folder with files which contain a datestamp like this:

```
string_DD-MM-YYYY_hhmm.pdf
```

to this format:

```
string_YYYY-MM-DD_hhmm.pdf
```

so that they sort by date when sorted by filename.

Example: `PB_KAZ_KtoNr_0463266665_01-02-2014_0341.pdf` should become `PB_KAZ_KtoNr_0463266665_2014-02-01_0341.pdf`.

I found this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273460/how-to-sort-files-in-bash-with-ddmmyy-timestamps-in-name) but it's regarding DDMMYYYY format instead of DD-MM-YYYY and the answeres are way to complicated for my situation. As the `string` always is the same in content and length (24 characters) a simple command, that splits and reassembles the string by positions would be sufficient.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you hint that "a simple command [....] would be sufficient", it is hard to image that you cannot get enough information to apply yourself reading `man sed(1)` or `man awk(1)`. did you consult the manual?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace thanks for pushing me in the right direction. As i'm new to this, i didn't know where o start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Perl‘s rename (standalone command):

```
rename -n 's/(.*)_(.*)-(.*)-(.*)_(.*.pdf)/$1_$4-$3-$2_$5/' *.pdf
```

If everything looks fine remove `-n`.

Comment: can use `s/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/$3-$2-$1/` to be specific to date format...

Comment: I think you should specify that `rename` exists in different forms in different distributions. I found useful [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238856/find-all-filename-mp4-and-rename-filename-audio/238862#238862).

Comment: works like a charm in Ubuntu 16.04! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @andreatsh: Thank you for this link. Anton, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a crude method, especially if there are a lot of files, but most basic one with awk:

It assumes you don't have any other pdf in folder, except string_DD-MM-YYYY_hhmm.pdf ones, and that string_ part is 24 characters long

`cd` to folder and then run this:

```
for i in *.pdf; do mv $i `\ls -1 $i | awk '{print substr ($0, 0, 24)}'``\ls -1 $i | awk -F[_.] '{print$(NF-1)}'| awk -F- '{print$3"-"$2"-"$1}'`.pdf; done
```

Comment: thanks! This would be exactly, what i asked for. But for some reason the datepart gets stripped completely, when i run this command. I'm now using the answer from Cyrus and Sundeep, as it is a bit more flexible. Thanks anyway!